# Фильтрация ввода в TextBox

Tags: c++-cli

Суть: нужно (помимо прочего) заблокировать ввод точки с запятой. Вот код событий KeyDown и KeyPress для текстбокса tbGroup.

```
private: System::Void tbGroup_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
             IncorSymbEntered = false;
             if ( (e->KeyCode == Keys::OemSemicolon) ||
                 ((Control::ModifierKeys == Keys::Shift) && (e->KeyCode == Keys::Oem4)))
                 IncorSymbEntered = true;
}
private: System::Void tbGroup_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) {
             if (IncorSymbEntered)
                 e->Handled = true;
}
```

первое условие в кейдауне отрабатывает, но так же блокирует ввод буквы "ж", что некстати. Второе просто почему-то не срабатывает, точка с запятой вводится. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить. Просто заблокировать буквы/цифры для других текстбоксов получилось, а тут не знаю как.